# Is there a command that works in mathjax but not in Latex?

Tags: packages, amsmath, matrices

In math.stackexchange site I saw who use this command `$\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$` for generating a matrix but the same command doesn't work in latex (at least using amsmath package).  I Know that I can use the environment `$\begin{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}$` but my question is:

> Is this command available only for mathjax or I should add a specific package to latex to use it?

Comment: To be a bit picky, your title ("is there a command available in MathJax but not LaTeX?") is different than your body (where "a command" becomes `\pmatrix`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pmatrix` is a command from plain TeX, if you really want to use it in latex you could use the `plain` package (but I don't recommend it)

Actually the plain tex version needs `\cr` not `\\` to end rows but mathjax is a loose emulation of plain and latex at the same time.